# Can I split the cold water to get hot water (using a tankless heater) for a shower?

Tags: tankless

I have a small "casita" (a bedroom-size building separate from my house) where we want to add a bathroom (shower + sink). Since there isn't water in that structure we're planning on piping just cold water (the hot water is much farther), and get a tankless water heater to generate "new" hot water from the cold one. I live in Florida so the cold water isn't too cold. Now my question is, will there be enough water pressure for a shower if I'm using just one pipe to generate the two of them?
If not, can I use one of those water pumps that increase the pressure? Where would you put it? inside or outside?
Are there other solutions that I'm not thinking about?
Thank you

Comment: to give a proper answer more info is needed. How far is the run with the water? What size pipe are you using? What water pressure do you have there? Is the electric service capable of powering a tankless heater and a pump if needed, as well as the other electrical requirements.  Depending on those answers, your plan could very well be viable.

Comment: It should be possible but depends on the distance.  Drop in pressure at the house and casita will happen if house and casita water is used at the same time.  Will need to know pressure in the house, size of pipes, and distance away for better answers.

Comment: How are you heating that area, if gas or propane, consider that for your fuel for hot water.

Answer (score 2):

People tend to confuse "pressure" and "flow".   If you've ever taken a water hose set to low flow (valve barely open), and put your thumb over the hose end, you saw where the force got considerable and it sprayed out quite forcefully past your thumb.  That's pressure but not much flow.

If you don't have enough flow from the house, a pressure pump won't increase the flow all that much. All it's doing is decreasing the pressure at the inlet side of the valve, which will increase flow *slightly* but not enough to make up for a too small pipe.  At worst the pump will draw a vacuum and start **cavitating** and breaking stuff.

Depending on how you set up your shower, you'll need a lot of flow because Americans love deluge showers dumping 2-3 gallons per minute.  In that case you'll need to make the cold water pipe 3/4" at least.   Now using two 1/2" pipes instead of a 3/4" pipe is one way to get the same cross-section of pipe, but you'll be disappointed with the hot water you get from the house, as it will lose so much heat to the earth around.

You might as well run a single pipe and heat the water locally.  Rather than larger pipe, you could downscale the shower to ~1 gallon per minute, like European showers. That seems like a poor aesthetic choice, I know, why do 1 GPM when 3 GPM is about the same price? HAHAHA we'll get to that.

### Electric out to the shed

Generally when extending electric to an outbuilding, there are two options worth talking about.

- Run a single 15A or 20A circuit (possibly a MWBC giving effectively 2 circuits).
- Run a 90A feeder and run a subpanel.

The reason for this is the cost of wire.  The next size larger than 20A *ranked by cost* is very large aluminum wire, which is perfectly safe at these large sizes.  Hence we make a quantum leap to 90A.

The only way you're going to run a water heater on 15/20A is by running a MWBC and placing a tanked heater on one leg of the MWBC.  That can work since garden variety 30/40 gallon tanked heaters *will work on 120V* just at 1/4 the power so 4 times the "recovery time". Since it only takes 1125W or about 9.3 amps, other things can be put on a 20A circuit.

However if you go the "big option" and run 90A feeder, now you can run tanked heaters normally, or tankless are also in play.

### Much ado about tankless

The hand-wringing over tankless is that they take a lot of power.  "Impractical amounts" some say.

Well I've crunched the numbers countless times* and Harper's Rule of Thumb is figure the GPM flow you need, multiply by 40 amps or 9600W.

This correlates to the British "electric shower". They are not costly ($250 for a reputable one) and they come in two sizes: 8500W and 9500W. The secret is a low flow showerhead: their flow is around 1 GPM given their climate for inlet water temperature.  Yours may vary in Florida.

Oh, and the British put the tankless heater a foot from the showerhead. That means hot water is pretty much instant. No need for a gimpy recirculating system.

So the British electric shower, used by millions all over Europe, is "proof of concept" for the viability of tankless **given good system design** - that low flow showerhead is the keystone of the project. The problem is, in America everyone expects a unit replacement:  Like Henry Ford once said, "people don't want cars, they want a faster horse". People want an EV that you take to a smelly toxic place once a week and spend 5 minutes refilling. They want a tankless that "drops in" to a house whose water system was never designed for tankless. That's how you get into 160A whole-house tankless units.  It's moronic.

In your setup I'd use a 40A or 50A tankless mounted right at the shower (just to show up those Brits lol), and take a tee off that for the sink.  Of course the person *in the shower* won't appreciate it none too much if someone else runs the sink, but "Don't use the sink, I'm in the shower" is nothing new for most people.

Comment: I was nonplussed to find a British shower with the water heater inside the shower enclosure, being showered along with the human. Seemed to be designed for that installation... but I come from a part of the US still tends to put bathroom light switches out in the hallway because we electrified while people were still being overprotective about that; quite a different mindset!

Comment: @keshlam yeah, the British over-rely on their "whole house 30mA RCD" and also have a disturbingly lackadaisical view toward ground rods.  For an electric shower to be in the shower in the US, it would need to be on a 5mA GFCI breaker.  Bathroom light in the hallway is a regular thing in Victorians. In my bathroom there's nowhere else to put it, since the tub is on the right and the vanity is immediately after the door swing.

Answer (score 1):

If you have adequate supply pressure and flow to your house, this is easily done with no auxiliary pump involved, but requires using adequate sized pipe from the house to the new structure, as well as having adequate power (or gas) at the new structure to run the heater.

- 1/2" pipe would likely be a problem at any distance.
- 3/4" pipe might work OK for a short distance.
- 1" pipe would very likely be adequate unless it's a terribly long
  distance.

The price of a pump will more than cover the cost differential to adequate-sized pipe so you don't need one, and pumps don't work all that well if the pipe supplying them is undersized, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run a single pipe to the casita and split it for a hot and cold supply. That is how the  city supply feeds your house. For the hot water, I would suggest that you install a small water heater with some storage. They come in different sizes and capacities . If you search the Home Depots and/or Lowes site they list numerous tanks and some even only need 120 volt supply. If you go for the instantaneous type they require a lot of electricity. You may also have to use licensed professionals in many cases. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

At my previous home, the water line coming in was 3/4 and I had no problems with pressure.

in your outbuilding, I would think you're not exactly filling a soaking tub and taking a shower at the same time!

I have to completely support what d.George said.   An on demand WH, if electric, requires **A LOT OF POWER**.  One of those point of use water heaters that hold a gallon or two is great if you just want to get hot water to wash your hands, minor other stuff, but are not adequate for a shower.  Unless you have very good power in your outbuilding or are planning on using natural gas or propane to fire an on-demand unit, I'd suggest a smallish tank type (25-40 gallons).   That will be plenty for all but the longest of showers and if electric, some only require 20 amps.  If you plan on taking long hot showers with high-flow heads, go bigger.  If just a quick rinse with a water saving head, you could probably do with a 25-30 gal tank type WH.

EDIT:  Also, electric tank type water heaters are dead simple:  A tank, a heating element and a thermostat. Other types are much more complex and require maintenance.

Lastly, and this is opinion based:  Tank type WHs are getting a bad rap as being inefficient. New ones are very well insulated and only consume power at a modest rate compared to electric tankless. Once the water is heated to set point, it takes very little power to maintain it there.

Due to stresses on the electrical grid caused by a variety of factors, including renewables and EV charging, I think it's responsible to "even out" our power usage, electric tankless is the opposite of that.   I may get snipped by a moderator for this last paragraph, but I though it was important to include.